# Acoustic Guitar: Remove gloss coating from an inexpensive acoustic

Tags: acoustic-guitar, maintenance, repair

I have just bought an inexpensive acoustic guitar. The guitar has a gloss coat on over the wood like most higher end ones, and I'm not the biggest fan of the shine. If this was a higher end guitar I'd just leave it, but feel comfortable removing the gloss from this one.

Any recommendations on the best general process to remove the gloss finish on an acoustic guitar?

Comment: I would think just wet sand with 600-1000-2000 grit sandpaper until you reach the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of flatting paper used on car bodies will do the job. On flat surfaces, like the top, use a small block to keep the paper flat. Start with around 280/320 wet and dry, gently, with soapy water, drying off often, until you see the result you like. Finish with around 500/600, or 1000 if you think necessary.